# Python: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-2.7, simplecv

Here is my code:

```
for ts, blob in izip(ts_list, blobs):
    ts = simplecvimg.track("camshift", i, fgmask,b.boundingBox())
    print(ts)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
  if not ts and not img:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

While I understand from here [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous) why one get's this error, I don't know what to do about this error in my situation. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: related?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

either `ts` or `img` is a numpy array ... as such it doesnt know what `not <numpy.array>` means

you probably want `if len(ts) > 0 and len(img) > 0`  , or maybe `if ts is not None` or something along those lines

```
>>> import numpy
>>> not numpy.array([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
 Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: The declarations are as follows: ts_list = [], with ts being each element in ts_list and f,img=cam.read(). I tried all 3 things you suggested to no avail.